# How did I get points for my non-answer?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

I [posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769593/16-04-headphones-detected-but-not-switched-on-automatically-after-startup/771030#771030) what I thought would be helpful info that might lead to an answer and got scolded because it wasn't actually an answer.

Whether that's right or not is not the issue (for me). What I want to know is how did my rep go up by 8 points? I'm not complaining! I just don't see where they came from.

Comment: You got an upvote (+10) and a downvote (-2) on the answer, which nets you +8 and leaves the post score at 0.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be something like that, but at my level, I can't see those details (or I don't know how to.) If it's worth the bother, you can post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see on [the reputation tab](https://askubuntu.com/users/23861/joe?tab=reputation) of your profile how your reputation is calculated.

There you see you have got one upvote (+10) and one downvote (-2) on that post (giving a net post score of 0, and 8 reputation).

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Your link took me right there.